# Pluralismo de las palabras

Tags: python, string

Hasta el momento tengo ya hecho el codigo para que adicione una 's' si termina en vocal o 'es' si termina en consonante, pero la cosa es que las palabras me aparecen de forma vertical una por una y no de forma horizontal como necesito.

```
lista=[]
vocales=['a','A','e','E','i','I','o','O','u','U']
consonantes=['B','b', 'C','c', 'D','d', 'F','f', 'G','g', 'H','h', 'J','j', 'K','k', 
'L','l', 'M','m', 'N','n', 'P','p', 'Q','q', 'R','r', 'S','s', 'T','t', 'V','v', 
'X','x', 'Z','z', 'W','w', 'Y','y']


frase=input('Ingrese la frase ')
split=frase.split()
try:
    for i in range(0,100):
        oracion=split[i]
        if oracion[-1] in vocales:
           oracion='{}s'.format(oracion)
        if oracion[-1] in consonantes:
           oracion='{}es'.format(oracion)
     print(oracion)
except:
    None
```

Agradezco de antemano a quien me pueda ayudar.

Esta es la respuesta que me arroja:

```
holases
mundoses
meses
llamoses
estebanes
muchoses
gustoses
```

Comment: para que usas el `for`? no es necesario

Comment: lo agregue para que el i funcione como indice y coja todas las palabras que hay en la cadena

Comment: pues creo que en más del 90% de los casos dará error

Comment: que me recomendarias hacer? , la verdad no tengo idea de como formularla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una de las tantas formas de hacerlo sería de esta forma.

```py
def pluralizar(oracion):
    oraciones = oracion.split()
    for i in range(len(oraciones)):
        if oraciones[i][-1].lower() in vocales: #con el lower solo verificamos las minusculas
            oraciones[i]+="s"

        elif oraciones[i][-1].lower() in consonantes:
            oraciones[i]+="es"
    return " ".join(oraciones)
```

Aquí he creado una función donde se recibe una oración y luego es separada en frases con el método `split` luego iteramos según el número de lementos y en caso cumpla con alguna condición la frase será modificada en la lista `oraciones`. Finalmente unimos todos los elementos de la lista y retornamos eso.

**Probamos**

```py
frase=pluralizar(input('Ingrese la frase: '))
print(frase)
```

**Resultado**

```
Ingrese la frase: buena cancion

buenas canciones
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Observación 1:

Usar una indexación con *ciclo-for* que no coincide con el tamaño de la lista `split`:

```py
for i in range(0,100):
    oracion=split[i]
```

Esta porción de código lanzará error cuando `len(split)` sea menor a 100.

Solucionar con cambios locales: `for i in range(len(split)):` poniendo `len(split)` que es el tamaño de la lista que estas indexando.

#### Observación 2:

El uso de *try/catch* es innecesario, ya que el código al ser corto (y determinístico) es apreciable que no hay lugar a errores. Al menos esta observación es subjetiva ya que es común que uno se equivoque en cuanto a si determinada porción de código puede lanzar un error o no.

Podrías dejarla tal cual, aunque me parece que no aporta nada al código. Una ves corriges el *ciclo-for* según al observación 1.

Salida **antes**:

```
Holases
mundoses
meses
llamoses
estebanes
muchoses
gustoses
```

#### Observación 3:

`print()` utiliza por defecto un carácter que indica salto de línea al final de mostrado el texto, que es lo que quieres evitar. Podrías definir a tu gusto el parámetro *end*, de esta forma:

```py
print(oracion,end=' ')
```

Así remplazarías el valor por defecto que no está escrito `end='\n'` por un espacio de separación entre palabras; `end=' '`

#### Observación 3

Dentro del `for` modificas la variable oraciones dentro de cada `if`, así que en el primer `if` le estás poniendo una consonante (*s*) al final de lo que hay en `oración` e inmediatamente esa *s* que pones al final te obliga siempre  a entrar en el `if` de las consonantes:

puedes cambiar el segundo `if` con `elif` ya que si se ejecuta uno esperas que no lo haga el otro (son casos mutuamente excluyentes):

Salida **antes**:

```
Holases mundoses meses llamoses estebanes muchoses gustoses
```

#### Resultado final, después de las tres observaciones:

```py
lista=[]
vocales=['a','A','e','E','i','I','o','O','u','U']
consonantes=['B','b', 'C','c', 'D','d', 'F','f', 'G','g', 'H','h', 'J','j', 'K','k', 
'L','l', 'M','m', 'N','n', 'P','p', 'Q','q', 'R','r', 'S','s', 'T','t', 'V','v', 
'X','x', 'Z','z', 'W','w', 'Y','y']


frase=input('Ingrese la frase ')
split=frase.split()

for i in range(len(split)):
    oracion=split[i]
    if oracion[-1] in vocales:
        oracion='{}s'.format(oracion)
    if oracion[-1] in consonantes:
        oracion='{}es'.format(oracion)
    print(oracion,end=' ')
```

Entrada:

```
Hola mundo me llamo esteban mucho gusto
```

Salida:

```
Holas mundos mes llamos estebanes muchos gustos
```